# How to use :before on child element?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a wordpress site and I use css to replace an image of a plugin (polylang's flags).

```
.lang-item-42 a img {
    content:url(/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/en.png);
}
```

So this is working on Chrome and Safari but not on Firefox and IE. As I found out is because I should use :before selector but im not sure where to put it because if I place it right after the "img" element it not works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should declare ::before with double colon (not :before) since it is considered a pseudo-element and not a pseudo-class.
Consider this element like "something that is inside and at the beginning of the element it is put on".
So if you want to put an image inside the link, you hide the other and type

```
.lang-item-42 a::before {
    content:url(/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/en.png);
}

.lang-item-42 a img {
    display: none;
}
```

I haven't tried this out but it should work.